# Picture generation does not work after URL redirect in .htaccess

Tags: url-rewrite, product-images, .htaccess

Picture generation does not work after URL redirect in .htaccess with the following script:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?